# query with multiple values for same attribute in dynamodb nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Is there any way to query a dynamodb table with multiple values for a single attribute?

```
      TableName: "sdfdsgfdg"
      IndexName: 'username-category-index',
      KeyConditions: {
        "username": {
          "AttributeValueList": { "S": "aaaaaaa@gmail.com" }
          ,
          "ComparisonOperator": "EQ"
        },
        "username": {
          "AttributeValueList": { "S": "hhhhh@gmail.com" }
          ,
          "ComparisonOperator": "EQ"
        },
        "category": {
          "AttributeValueList": { "S": "Coupon" }
          ,
          "ComparisonOperator": "EQ"
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BachGetItem` API can be used to get multiple items from DynamoDB table. However, it **can't** be used in your use case as you are getting the data from **index**.

> The BatchGetItem operation returns the attributes of one or more items
>   from one or more tables. You identify requested items by primary key.

In API perspective, there is no other solution. You may need to look at data modelling perspective and design the table/index to satisfy your Query Access Pattern (QAP).

Also, please note that querying the index multiple times with partition key values (i.e. some small number) wouldn't impact the performance as long as it is handful of items.